# Project created from template has wrong solution properties

Tags: .net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have a class library project template that has only project file and AssemblyInfo files. This is content of the project file from the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- This adds default build flavors -->
  <Import Project="..\common.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{$guid1$}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>$safeprojectname$</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>$safeprojectname$</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

After I add new project using this template wrong properties are added to the solution. Here is part of solution file that is being added:

```
    {C12D9BEF-3A1D-4E99-B314-35D92D8F5BC1}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {C12D9BEF-3A1D-4E99-B314-35D92D8F5BC1}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {C12D9BEF-3A1D-4E99-B314-35D92D8F5BC1}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {C12D9BEF-3A1D-4E99-B314-35D92D8F5BC1}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {C12D9BEF-3A1D-4E99-B314-35D92D8F5BC1}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {C12D9BEF-3A1D-4E99-B314-35D92D8F5BC1}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
```

As you can see `Debug|Any CPU` is specified for the `Release` configurations. What should I do to make template work correctly?